# Apache wordpress permission problems

Tags: permissions, apache2

I'm trying to setup LAMP on my Ubuntu server and got most of it working, but I'm struggling with permissions..

Right now I can't install wordpress b/c it is unable to write the config file.. And on a wordpress installed I moved from my old server, it won't let me upload any images.

I guess this is a permission issue, but I'm unsure how to solve it..

A few screenshots of my settings

[image]

[image]

public_html is where files are stored..

I used these tutorials to setup Apache, FTP, phpmyadmin

> digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts
>
> digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-for-a-user-s-directory-on-ubuntu-16-04

But I got confused about all the chown and chmod parts..

Can anyone spot from the screenshots, what I have done wrong and how do I correct it?

If more information is needed, please tell me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reviewing your output it looks as if Apache is running under the user account 'www-data".  However your files/directories are owned by 'martin:martin'.

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/
```

The above chown (change owner) command will make the directory owner 'www-data' which will match the service owner for Apache.  The second command sets the correct permissions for the public_html directory.

If the above does not work for you include the following.

A clear description of how far you got in the tutorials along with exactly where you are stuck in the process.

- OS, Apache, Wordpress versions
- Include httpd.conf
- Include apache log

Comment: Thank you.. I think the www-data user was made in desperation when I tried all possible fixes i could find on forums.. But I can now upload images and installed the wordpress on the other domain..